# VB.net Precompiled site, and adding a template column with Date differences

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagrid

I have a vendor application which is precompiled. I want to add a template column into the aspx page, however I'm having some difficulty.

This works for me fine as "Available" is a column bound to the asp DataGrid:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="test">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" Text='<% #DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Available") %>' runat="server"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Now, I'm trying to basically create a template column, that takes the (int) "Available" column and divide it by 12 and then multiply by DateTime.Now.Date.Month.

I'm not having any luck with using DateTime within <% %> on this page.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `inherits="Archive, App_Web_XXXXX"` from `<%@ Page %>` then bring your code into ASPX file and modify it.

Comment: No way to do it just with the page size though, without changing the inherited code behind?

Comment: I don't think so. When you add new asp.net element to the page, source code must be updated